# Jquery mobile with knockout checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, checkbox

I have a checkbox that needs another checkbox selected before its legal to select it. If selecting the checkbox is illegal I want to unselect it. The code goes like this:

```
if (self.Advances()[i].Bought()) { 
    break;
} else {
    advance.Bying(false);
    $("#" + advance.Id).checkboxradio('refresh');
    return;
}
```

Inspecting the knockout object and the DOM both the value and the checkbox is correctly not set when the else above hits. The GFX is however not uppdated so the checkbox is still visualy checked.

After experimenting a bit I found that introducing a javascript error in the refresh line actually led to everything working as expected (wich was unexpected) IE the following works:

```
if (self.Advances()[i].Bought()) { 
    break;
} else {
    advance.Bying(false);
    //parent is not a check box, so error is thrown. 
    $("#" + advance.Id).parent().checkboxradio('refresh'); 
    return;
}
```

This led me to belive that JQM is triggered in the wrong order (IE the refresh I manually do above is triggered BEFORE the refresh from the mouse event)

So I ended up with the following (working but inelegant) solution using setTimeout:

```
if (self.Advances()[i].Bought()) { 
    break;
} else {
    setTimeout(function () {
        advance.Bying(false);
        $("#" + advance.Id).checkboxradio('refresh');
    }, 250);
    return;
}
```

My question is there anyway I can force JQM to do the refreshes in the right order? Or is this a bug in JQM or is there something I don't understand about how JQM works?

Edit: The whole code (and site) can be found on civ.testmaskin.com

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7804968/1061602. I use knockout custom bindings for this sort of thing. I don't have a checkbox one to hand unfortunately.

Comment: I do not understand how a custom binding will solve my problem? Could you explain what the purpose of such a handler would be?