# Odd behaviour KnockoutJS and jQuery Mobile checkbox

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I have a login page with a remember me checkbox, all in jQuery Mobile. I'm also using KnockoutJs.

[image]

I have a model that is defined as follow:

```
MOX.Login = function()
{
   var self = this;

   self.Username = ko.observable("");
   self.Password = ko.observable("");
   self.IsRememberMe = ko.observable(true);
}
```

In my viewmodel I do the following:

```
self.Login = ko.observable(new MOX.Login()); //login data
```

There is nothing else I do with this object.

The html for the checkbox is as follow:

```
<label for="chkRememberLogin" data-bind="text: GetLabel('lblRememberLogin')"></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkRememberLogin" data-bind="checked: Login().IsRememberMe" />
```

I might expect that as the default value of the IsRememberMe property is set to true, the checkbox is set to true. When I set a regular checkbox on the page with the same binding, it is checked.
When I check the value it is set to true.

Also, when I tap the checkbox, the first time, it stays unchecked. The value of IsRememberMe is indeed false. The second time I tap, the value is changed to true and also the checkbox is checked.

How can I make sure that the first time the checkbox is checked?

Side question, when I set the IsRememberMe to false per default. It is always true after initializing. How come?

Comment: You might want to check this (as when using 3rd libs, knockout often needs custom bindings) : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19706231/384701

Comment: @billy Thx, that worked. Still wondering why the rest of the checkboxes are working properly, except this one.

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with your `MOX` namespace or some of the rest of your code that you didn't post. Check this [simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwisch45/B9r2K/1/) - none of the problems you listed are occurring here.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is to make sure that you checkbox is not actually rendering and just not shifted over so you can't see it. Jquery mobile needs to have the fresh property after rendering a dynamic element on checkboxes. I would set the checkbox to data-enhance="false" just to make sure this is not a conflict.